# $\|a_{n+1} - a_n\| = o(1/n^{1/3}) \Rightarrow \|\bar{a}_{n+1} - \bar{a}_n\| = o(1/n^{4/3})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, average

To put simply:

When $\bar{a}_n$ is the average of $a_k$ up to $n$ and $\| \cdot \|$ is Euclidean norm,
$$
\|a_{n+1} - a_n\| = o(1/n^{\epsilon}) \Rightarrow \|\bar{a}_{n+1} - \bar{a}_n\| = o(1/n^{1+\epsilon})?
$$

It should be intuitively, but I can't prove it. This (if true) will imply that $\bar{a}_n$ will converge to a point, right?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense as stated. Where are the $a_n$? By $t$ do you mean $n$? What is $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy question. Yes, I meant $n$ by $t$, and $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm and $a_n \in \mathbb{R}^L$. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire thing is **false** if $\epsilon<1$. Let's say WLOG they're real numbers. Put $r\in(\epsilon,1)$, and $a_n=n^{1-r}$, so your condition is clearly satisfied since $a_{n+1}-a_n=n^{1-r}[(1+\frac{1}{n})^{1-r}-1]=(1-r)n^{-r}+O(n^{-r-1})$. Then $n\overline{a}_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1-r}$ satisfies (similar argument to the proof of the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence))
$$ \frac{(n+1)^{2-r}-1}{2-r}=\int_1^{n+1}x^{1-r}dx\geq \sum_{k=1}^n k^{1-r}
\geq \int_0^{n}x^{1-r}dx=\frac{n^{2-r}}{2-r}.$$

Hence $\overline{a}_n = \frac{1}{2-r}n^{1-r}+O(n^{-r})$ so we obtain once more
$\overline{a}_{n+1}-\overline{a}_n=\frac{1-r}{2-r}n^{-r}+O(n^{-r-1})$, which is **not** $o(n^{-1-\epsilon})$. In particular, $\overline{a}_n$ is divergent.

A similar result can be proven for $\epsilon>1$, but in that case, you do get convergence for $a_n$ (since the sequence is Cauchy) and then for $\overline a_n$. (The case $\epsilon=1$ can yield different things.)

PS: Please write your questions more clearly.

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.